# Literary magazines with the fastest turnaround rate?

Tags: creative-writing, magazines

I know Clarkesworld will send you a yes/no within a week or so. How do I find magazines that take a relatively short time period to review a story?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [The Submission Grinder](http://thegrinder.diabolicalplots.com/). Go to the [Advanced Search](http://thegrinder.diabolicalplots.com/Search/ByFilter) page & enter parameters. Eg, I just searched F and SF markets, entered Minimum Pay of 5c per word, Max Average Response Time of 10 days with Sort By 'Avg Response Days' and got back a list of 5 markets (plus others with no data); changing the Max Response to 30 days, resulted in 14 more markets.